# Eclipse terminated with exit value 0

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse on Mac. I get the following error each time I run an application on Eclipse:

terminated, exit value: 0 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (Nov 16, 2015 5:16:10 PM)

For your reference:

→ /usr/libexec/java_home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home

→ java  -version

java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

→ cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

→ JavaVirtualMachines

→ ls

1.6.0.jdk

Please help!

Comment: Does this happen for any application you run or for a specific one?  If for a specific one is it multi threaded ?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? What was the name of the file you downloaded?

Comment: That just means your application finished running.

Answer (score 1):

"Terminated" means the program finished, and exit code 0 means "normal completion." So basically Eclipse says "your program is done."